# Series Electrolitic Cap life

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, electrolytic-capacitor, reliability

My country has 230V mains.
Many imported SMPS have a 230/115 VAC switch that means that the SMPS cap filter input stage runs like a fullwave bridge here.  It means that it runs like a full wave voltage doubler in the USA.
This switchable input stage is common and accepted.  In fact there is a chip that senses mains voltage to automate the voltage selection switch.

On the face of it this dual volt scheme is cheap reliable and could be made idiot proof.  The only penalty is two electrolytic capacitors that will occupy more space and cost more money than one.  This penalty is not a showstopper.  When on 230VAC the two electrolytic capacitors are in series but I always see balancing resisters so the expected 350VDC will balance out nicely on say two 470 microfarad 250V caps.

Why are the caps much more likely to blow?
A coworker said that it is due to "uneven aging" is he correct?

Comment: Those balancing resistors (or some equivalent setup) are [definitely recommended](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/CD00222186.pdf) but I've seen cheap SMPSes (ATX mainly) not use them. And the few dead ones I've seen the caps were not seriously out of balance but the main switchers died [in tandem] anyway.

Comment: And yeah, [they're recommended](http://www.richtek.com/en/Products/AC_DC/Half-Bridge%C2%A0Controller/R7521) for half-bridge designs too. This latter circuit is probably what you had in mind on the input side.

Comment: The half bridge was and still is popular ,Surely they wouldnt have returned the SMPS transformer primary to the cap junction. Normally I would see metal film DC blocking caps .

Answer (score 1):

The circuit in question looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRMOJx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the switch is open for 230 VAC operation, the four diodes work as a bridge rectifier, putting pulses of current into both capacitors at 2× the line frequency.

When the switch is closed for 120 VAC operation, D3 and D4 never conduct, and D1 and D2 function as a voltage doubler. C1 and C2 are charged separately on opposite half-cycles of the AC input, and each one sees pulses at 1× the line frequency.

What this means is that in the latter configuration, the ripple current for each capacitor is twice as high. Ripple current is the primary contributor to internal heating in an electrolytic capacitor, and heat is the primary limitation on electrolytic capacitor life. The heating effect is proportional to the square of the current, so even though the pulses occur half as often, you still get twice the heat.

Comment: Dave Tweed  good to see the diagram .What We would find is that on 230VAC where its just a full bridge the caps would often start to rupture .So many computer PSU died this way .